# How to convert spontaneous emission into stimulated?

Tags: led, semiconductors, laser, solid-state-devices

I have a semiconductor diode that has **spontaneous** emission (*LED*).

The question is what can I change in the fabrication of the diode to improve its performance such that the diode gains a **stimulated** emission like a laser.

I asked my professor for help and he told me to make the procedure in 4 steps. I do not know if there is a standard way of doing this **conversion from spontaneous to stimulated emission**.

Comment: Pretty sure no "conversion" is possible here. You might want to ask what is the difference between LED and laser perhaps, but that is better to be done on Physics SE.

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/280542/whats-the-difference-between-a-laser-diode-and-ordinary-led/354795#354795

Comment: Also consider the physical differences between [LED geometry](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Electronic/led.html) and [laser geometry](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/optmod/qualig.html#c2).

Comment: https://www.explainthatstuff.com/semiconductorlaserdiodes.html

Answer (score 2):

Well the conversion of spontaneous to stimulated emission is a part of the lasing process. My recommendation is that you you take look at the a book on lasers, my personal recommendation is : "Introduction to Laser Technology, Fourth edition. C. Breck Hitz, J. Ewing, and J. Hecht", its super easy to read and it teaches you the fundamentals.

Here's an illustration from that book that might be a good explainer:
[image: Cascading the spontaneous emissions to make it stimulated]

In each of the rods, you basically have a lasing effect as shown down here:
[image]

In some cases you use the same principle and skip having a cascade by adding a resonator:
[image]

References -
All illustrations are from the book "Introduction to Laser Technology, Fourth edition. C. Breck Hitz, J. Ewing, and J. Hecht"

Comment: Hmm it wouldn't hurt to add something about what is in the jar and how it is stimulated, like what makes something qualify as a stimulable material.  I assume "stimulated" means energy is added to the material somehow that causes it to emit the extra photons seen from identical jars in the diagram.

Comment: Go [here](https://youtu.be/lLTfMLaX820?t=573) in a youtube video by Dan Gelbart. I've set the time correctly in that link to start you just where you need to be on lasers. Listen to the discussion and realize that many folks did **not** understand how this all works in theory, at first. The details are non-trivial, in practice. That said, the implementation isn't that difficult once you've worked out the fact that certain circumstances can be made to work.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't go into what happens in the jar because I'd have to talk about things like population inversion and emission lines and bandgaps. The resource I pointed would do a better job than me in explaining in a stackexchange post.

Comment: I just found a related post: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/280542/whats-the-difference-between-a-laser-diode-and-ordinary-led?noredirect=1&lq=1